# Using Powershell within a form

Tags: powershell

So I create a window with buttons, but I want to nest a shell inside the window for some of the functions, rather than open a new window.

For example, a different part of the script prompts the user for a target and then performs commands against that computer. I want to do all that, from this form in a shell

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Dan's Security Tool"
$Icon = New-Object system.drawing.icon 
("c:\users\sadmiller2\documents\icon.ico")
$Form.Icon = $Icon
$Image = 
[system.drawing.image]::FromFile("c:\users\sadmiller2\pictures\defender.jpg") 
$Form.BackgroundImage = $Image
$Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "None"
# None, Tile, Center, Stretch, Zoom
$Form.Width = $Image.Width
$Form.Height = $Image.Height
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",20,
[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
# Font styles are: Regular, Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikeout
$Form.Font = $Font
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "Dan's Security Tool"
$Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Label.ForeColor = "White"
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(485,25)

$ContinueButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ContinueButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,590)
$ContinueButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
$ContinueButton.Text = "Continue"
$ContinueButton.Add_MouseHover({$ContinueButton.backcolor = [System.Drawing.Color]::DarkGray})
$ContinueButton.Add_MouseLeave({$ContinueButton.backcolor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White})
$ContinueButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $ContinueButton
$form.Controls.Add($ContinueButton)

$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Can you include some code and what you have tried so far? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask questions that are most likely to be answered effectively.

Comment: You can also look at Sapien powerShell Studio, Admin Script Editor and Visual Studio 2017. They all offer GUI building with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to enable 'Multiline' property or something similar on the text box.

Assuming the Handle of the textbox is `$textbox1`, and you have the data to be displayed stored in a `$output` variable, display the output like

```
$textbox1.Text = $output
```

Comment: Could I reverse for an input box and still use it to run commands similar to read-host?

    $target = $textbox2.txt